# How to convert data from subquery in Json format?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use ORM to take dat from DB:

```
$products = Products::with("categories")->get();
```

When I do JSON response:

```
return response()->json(["producst" => $products]);
```

So, I get the following response:

```
{
  "products": {
    "total": 727,
    "per_page": "20",
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 37,
    "next_page_url": "",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 20,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 782,
        "price": "1.9",
        "object_id": "47",
        "available": "1",
        "categories": {

         "names": {
              "id": 14,
              "parent_id": "0",
              "active": "1",
              "title": "Stron",
              "description": ""
            }
          }
      }
```

Problem is that in response I get wrong format JSON here:

```
"categories": {...}
```

It should be: `"categories": []` because inside can be some elements.

How can I do this in Laravel?

Comment: Did you try like this : return $products->toJson(); ?

Comment: can u kindly provide ur table colmns structure??

Comment: For what `toJson()` if I use `response()->json()`

Comment: Can you show `categories` relation function of product model?

Answer (score 0):

By looking your json data it seems that `categories` function is returning a model object, not collection.

This can be caused by a wrong relationship in the `product` model. So the correct relation should be as:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
}
```